# Aliasing Table in SQL Server and Using Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, exists

I am trying to understand exactly how Exists works so I made this quick temp table to try and get my head wrapped around it.

```
Drop Table #mytesttable
create table #mytesttable (edate date, num decimal(4,0), stat varchar(8),etype varchar(12))
insert into #mytesttable 
values ('20180401',1,'E','A/W'),
('20180101',1,'E','A/W'),
('20180701',1,'E','A/W'),
('20181001',1,'E','A/W'),
('20190101',1,'E','A'),
('20190301',1,'I','NULL'),
('20190101',2,'E','A'),
('20190301',2,'E','A'),
('20180901',2,'E','A'),
('20190101',3,'E','NULL'),
('20190301',3,'I','NULL'),
('20180901',3,'I','NULL')
```

When executing the query below I get three rows returned when I would expect only 1.

```
Select *
From #mytesttable
Where edate = '20190101'
and stat = 'E'
and exists(Select *
From #mytesttable sub
Where  sub.num = num
and sub.etype  = 'A/W'
and sub.edate < '20190101')
```

Result:

```
edate   num stat    etype
2019-01-01  1   E   A
2019-01-01  2   E   A
2019-01-01  3   E   NULL
```

When I use the full name of the table in the top query to reference the column name in the exists statement I am matching on I get the results I would expect.

```
Select *
From #mytesttable
Where edate = '20190101'
and stat = 'E'
and exists(Select *
From #mytesttable sub
Where  sub.num = #mytesttable.num
and sub.etype  = 'A/W'
and sub.edate < '20190101')
```

Results (Correct):

```
edate   num stat    etype
2019-01-01  1   E   A
```

So is the exists statement getting confused and thinking it is matching num from the #mytesttable to itself. That is to say, is it looking at this as:

```
#mytesttable inner join #mytesttable
on num = num
```

And as soon as it evaluates to True it doesn't even look at the Where clause? If someone could shed some light on this that would be awesome.

Comment: qualify *all* column references; best practice is to assign a *unique* alias to every table reference, and then qualify column references using the unique alias. (even if you don't need to, it will make the intent more clear to any future reader.) So, assign an alias to the outermost table reference, for example. **`t`**, and then qualify the reference in the exists subquery  `sub.num = t.num`.  (Just so we're clear... this isn't an issue with EXISTS,  it's an issue with how SQL resolves column references, looking at the innermost/closest FROM clause first, before looking to an outer query)

Comment: @spencer7593 Thank you for the clarification. I thought that by aliasing the table in the exists statement it would prevent just "num" from resolving the name reference there. I was very wrong.

Comment: The `sub` alias and qualifying the column reference with `sub.` is all fine. There's nothing wrong with that. The issue is just the unqualified column reference. And this issue is one of the reasons for our recommended pattern: "assign unique table alias to every table reference" and "qualify all column references"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to scope/visibility of column:

> [Subqueries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> **The general rule is that column names in a statement are implicitly qualified by the table referenced in the FROM clause at the same level.** If a column does not exist in the table referenced in the FROM clause of a subquery, it is implicitly qualified by the table referenced in the FROM clause of the outer query.

So your first query has join:

```
From #mytesttable sub
Where  sub.num = num
<=>
FROM #mytesttable sub
WHERE sub.num = sub.num   --always true for NOT NULL column
```

I suggest to follow [EIBTI](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGlossary)('Explicit Is Better Than Implicit') principle and explicitly qualify all columns with table aliases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the reference. I will try to follow the EBIT principal going forward. It's one of those thing that I mostly ignore and it still works out fine, but I can see how this might bite me in the future.